# CDI, Hibernate JSF on jetty

Tags: hibernate, jetty, cdi, jboss-weld

I am trying to make Weld, hibernate, jsf combination work on Jetty. The best approach I found on internet was http://www.laliluna.de/articles/2011/01/12/jboss-weld-jpa-hibernate.html .
It was a pain to clean up the dependencies, but I managed to go through that. 
Now it works for me except the initialization part of the EntityManagerStoreImpl. It seems the weld listener for jetty does not produce a ContainerInitialized event, so the init method which observes this event is never called. 
Could you tell me please what is the best way to bootstrap this class in the jetty environment?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to Use @PostConstruct annotation. Simple!